# In Girl, why does the main character freak out over the couple?

Tags: girl-daoko

[*Girl*](http://animatorexpo.com/girl/) may be a visual masterpiece, but its meaning is completely lost on me.  Or rather, the meaning of these two scenes:

[image]

The start of the whole scene happens around 7:35.  The main character is recreating the world in her own, unique way, and a couple walks by.  It does appear as if the main character is initially put off or curious about what they're doing so close to each other, but I can't think of anything that provoked her to freak out in the manner that she did.

The [lyrics near that part](https://foregroundnoises.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/daoko-girl-side-b-%E3%82%86%E3%82%81%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A6%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97-part-22/) don't really provide context, either.

> 足りないものしかない
>
> 足りないものしかみえない
>
> あたし以外のすべて
>
> きらめいてみえる理由

> There's nothing but things that aren't enough
>
> I can't see anything but things that aren't enough
>
> Everything, except for myself
>
> Has a reason to sparkle

I sort of understand that the main character is alone and has been alone for a while, but...the freak-out just doesn't make any sense based on what we'd seen up to that point.

Could anyone shed some light on this?  I'm...confused.

Answer (score -3):

ME!ME!ME! is the AMV the boy and the girl are from (the couple).The blue haired girl was a character in it, she kept getting the boys attention, in ME!ME!ME! he was addicted to porn and sex and the blue haired one was a porn star he watched. the boy wasn't giving his girlfriend (the pink haired one) any attention and the boy fell asleep watching the porn and in his dream he had a nightmare about his girlfriend turning into some monster wanting his love, it was actually her showing her despair. So when the blue haired one comes back in the new AMV and she see's them back together she loses her mind because she wants (supposedly) all of his attention back.

Comment: are you saying that all 3 character in the screenshot in the question all come from an Anime Music Video which is typically fan made?

Comment: ME!ME!ME! is not an AMV. it is an serie of ova's, [or something like that](http://otakumode.com/news/54706b7f00516cde135ca5c8/Japanese-Animator-Expo-Vol-3-Me!-Me!-Me!-Reveals-an-Extreme-Anime-Music-Video?lang=en). it is a collaboration between[Dwango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwango_%28company%29) and [Khara studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khara_%28studio%29)